# GET request ajax blocked by CORS policies -

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, get

I am trying to do a get request in my front end with ajax.
I am getting job_id from my backend Flask Python with {{job_id}}.

Here is my front-end ajax request :

```
function resultNotebook() {
  var jobRaw = '{{job_id}}';
  var job = jobRaw.split("&#39;").join('"');
  var id = job.replace(/\D/g,'');
 
  console.log(job);
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax(
    "https://adb.14.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get",
    {
      type: "get",
      headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer <TOKEN>' },
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "run_id":id 
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      },
    }
  );
}
document.getElementById("execute").addEventListener("click", resultNotebook);
```

I tryed using flask_cors as follow in my app but it still get this error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://adb.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get?run_id=10211260'
> from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Here is what i have in my backend :

```
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```

Comment: What does `headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer <TOKEN>' },` do? I'm not great with CORS stuff, but a get request shouldn't need any kind of authorization. If you need to pass data in a get req, it should be part of the url parms.

Comment: The api require the user to be authentified before making any request that's why it need a token. The data { "run_id" : id} translate into run_id=id in the Url.